# Show jQueryUI datepicker on button press without involving input field

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

In an ASP.NET project, I'm looking for a way to have a jQueryUI datepicker come up when I press a button, then cause a postback when a date is selected.  I've gotten the postback part working using [this method](http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2003/06/04/8260.aspx), but I'm having trouble either getting the picker to go away when I want it to or to behave properly when a date is selected.

I've tried:

- Attaching the picker to the button itself, but it sets the text of the button to the chosen date after I select and before the postback happens, which I don't want.
- Attaching the picker to the button and setting the `altField` option to an `<input type='text' />` that's positioned outside the browser window, but it still sets the text of the button when a date is chosen.
- Making it inline by attaching it to a `div` and creating it in the `onclick` of the button.  But according to [this forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/done-button-does-not-show-when-using-inline-datepicker), the inline datepicker by design doesn't show a Done button, and I can't dismiss it by clicking outside of it.

  - I tried adding a Done button of my own to the datepicker's button container (that shows up when `showButtonPanel` is set), but it goes away when the month or year changes and none of the events I can bind to seem to allow me to add it back.
  - I tried attaching a `mouseup` handler to the document body so I can dismiss the datepicker when I click outside it, but that triggers when I click in the datepicker too, and seems to prevent the picker from working at all.

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used a hidden `input` field before and attached a datepicker to it with successful results:

```
$("#date").datepicker({...}); // #date has style display='none'

$("#show-date").click(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker("show");
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7pttr/

Comment: This worked after some fiddling.  Interestingly enough, I get a Javascript error on `$('#myHiddenInput').datepicker('show');` if the hidden input is not the first child of its parent.  Tricky!